# Identify decorative font

Tags: font-identification, serif

I am trying to identify the following font but have come to a dead end.

The closest I have been able to get are:

- ITC Century Handtooled
- ITC Garamond Handtooled Volume
- Walburn Tooled
- Walburn Tooled Caps

but none of these are quite right (note the S and the E).

I have adjusted the image to make it a bit more readable.

[image: font]

Any ideas?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 2):

It took a bit of searching but I eventually identified this font.

It is **Atlantic Inline Normal**.